# Save UIImage in application path

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimage

(sorry for my english)

I need save an image in the application path and after load the image on ImageView.

To get the application path:

```
NSString * imagePath = NSHomeDirectory(); 
imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/image.png"];
```

After, to save the image:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);
[imageData writeToFile:self.imagePath atomically:YES]
```

To load the image saved on app path

```
self.imageSaved.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.imagePath];
```

The problem is that the image wasn´t save into the path

Regards

**Edit:**

Problem solved, only i need change the path for file

```
[imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/image.png"];
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   NSString *imagePath = NSHomeDirectory();
   imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Documents/image.png"];
```

or

```
   imagePath = [imagePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/image.png"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't save there on iOS applications.  You can only save into your documents directory.

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
    NSUserDomainMask, YES);

docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

**EDIT** I guess what I should say is you SHOULD only save files to the documents directory if they are files like the one you are creating in your example.

Comment: I think you are wrong about only being able to save to Documents. You could also save to Library or other folders as long as it's in a subfolder of the home directory.

Comment: Ok, so you can, but according to the File System Programming guide "You should not use this directory [Library] for user data files."

Comment: According to the ios data storage guidelines /Documents directory will be automatically backed up by iCloud. Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the <Application_Home>/Library/Caches directory. https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/