# Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 only in the simulator

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, nsfilemanager

I have an Ipad App, which download different files from the Internet. This App works great when I use the Xcode Simulator. When I try the App on the Ipad, I have an error at the beginning of the App, and with this error the App didn't work.

```
error creating directory in createPath: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x2d3eb0 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/DE851748-0D7A-4416-9B62-8EEEF9B80533/Cache, NSUnderlyingError=0x2cb8e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

My code to create a folder :

```
-(void) createPath{
NSError *error;

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:masterFolder
                               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&error];
     if (error != nil) {
         NSLog(@"error creating directory in createPath: %@", error);

     }

}
```

Here my variables:

```
masterFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Cache/"];
```

That is an old problem with the Code 513 I know, I explain what I've done until now:

1. I remove manually the App from the Simulator(reset) and from the Ipad
2. Change StringByAppendingString into StringByAppendingPathComponent like here:  [Save UIImage in application path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995993/save-uiimage-in-application-path/9996216)
3. I have used the standard folder "Cache" from Apple like here [NSFileManager creating folder (Cocoa error 513.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439408/nsfilemanager-creating-folder-cocoa-error-513)
4. and yes, I have rebooted my Mac ;)

And many more Sites. But I don't understand why the Simulator works differently like the original Ipad. Or did I overseen something?!? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I just change my folder and it works

```
masterFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Cache/"];
```

in

```
masterFolder = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Documents/"];
```

But why ? I don't know.
On this site you see the differences between the different kinds of folders 
[1](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/directories-temp-cache-documents/) Directories: Temp, Cache, Documents

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it has anything to do with the case of the filename?

iOS is case sensitive and OSX isn't, therefore something may work on the simulator that does not on iOS due to this.